# Mediawiki redirect to the edit of a non existing page

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I am making adding an Action with an extension

The problem is I need to redirect to the edit section of a page that does not exist

I tried this

```
<?php
public function onSubmit( $data ) {

    $title = Title::newFromText( $stringTitle );
    $newArticle = Article::newFromTitle( $title, $this->getOutput() );
    $editor = new EditPage( $newArticle );

    if( count($errors) > 0 ){
        return $errors;
    }

    $editor->edit();
    return false;
}
```

But it sends me to edit the current page not the new one with a different title

I also tried this

```
$title = Title::newFromText( $stringTitle );
global $wgOut;
$wgOut->redirect( $title->getFullURL() );
```

I does redirect to the desired page but not in edit mode

Answer (score 2):

Try $wgOut->redirect( $title->getFullURL( 'action=edit' ) );